# How to insert pictures into each individual bar in a ggplot graph

Tags: r, image, ggplot2

I'm trying to compare different NBA rookies across different stats, and I thought the graph would look great if I could add the player's face at the end of the graph like in the [r/dataisbeautiful graphs](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/dqndng/40_years_of_fleets_by_flag_oc/).
My code is currently this:

```
a3 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Player,
                         PPM),
             y = PPM)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           aes(fill = Player)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = PPM), size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 1),
            hjust = -0.1) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("Player") +
  ylab("Points Per Minute") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

This is what my graph currently looks like[image: like]

Comment: Have you seen this blog post, looks quite relevant: https://jcarroll.com.au/2019/08/13/ggtext-for-images-as-x-axis-labels/

Comment: The `ggtext` package seems to allow this: https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtext#markdown-in-theme-elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including images on axis label in an animated ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973129/including-images-on-axis-label-in-an-animated-ggplot2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You didn't provide a reprex, so I need to make something up. I would probably do it like this.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtextures)
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.9.39
#> Enabled features: cairo, fontconfig, freetype, lcms, pango, rsvg, webp
#> Disabled features: fftw, ghostscript, x11

data <- tibble(
  count = c(5, 6, 6, 4, 2, 3),
  animal = c("giraffe", "elephant", "horse", "bird", "turtle", "dog"),
  image = list(
    image_read_svg("http://steveharoz.com/research/isotype/icons/giraffe.svg"),
    image_read_svg("http://steveharoz.com/research/isotype/icons/elephant.svg"),
    image_read_svg("http://steveharoz.com/research/isotype/icons/horse.svg"),
    image_read_svg("http://steveharoz.com/research/isotype/icons/bird.svg"),
    image_read_svg("http://steveharoz.com/research/isotype/icons/turtle.svg"),
    image_read_svg("http://steveharoz.com/research/isotype/icons/dog.svg")
  )
)

ggplot(data, aes(animal, count, fill = animal, image = image)) +
  geom_isotype_col(
    img_height = grid::unit(1, "null"), img_width = NULL,
    ncol = 1, nrow = 1, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I wanted to ask if it was possible to display two images on the same bar on here (I'm assuming by messing with the hjust value) by having something like this: ggplot(data, aes(animal, count, fill = animal, image = image & x))

Comment: Please post a separate top-level question for this.

Comment: Just did @Claus Wilke
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58793147/how-to-insert-several-images-into-a-bar-graph-using-ggtextures-and-ggplot

Comment: This is very useful. Is there a plan to get ggtextures on CRAN?

Comment: No. There is now ggpattern which is much more powerful. https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggpattern

Comment: There is any way to position the images outside the bar (at the end bar)?