# Making the images go over the barcharts in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot with a few issues that I'm trying to solve. It's inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58677247/how-to-insert-pictures-into-each-individual-bar-in-a-ggplot-graph) post.

The plot:
[image]

My questions:

- I'm showing the top 3 and bottom 3 teams. I want to indicate this somehow on the plot. How do add text on the x-axis which groups them into top 3 and bottom 3?
- The logo for Wolfsburg is partially hidden. How do I make the logos either go at the end of the barchart, or above, so that they are fully visible?

My code:

```
data <- tibble(
  Diff_home_perc = c(-0.3, -0.2, -0.1,-0.05, 0.2, 0.3),
  Team = c("A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F"),
  ind = c("Green","Green","Green","Red","Red","Red"),
  image = list(
    image_read_svg("https://www.bundesliga.com/assets/clublogo/DFL-CLU-00000G.svg"),
    image_read_svg("https://www.bundesliga.com/assets/clublogo/DFL-CLU-000017.svg"),
    image_read_svg("https://www.bundesliga.com/assets/clublogo/DFL-CLU-000018.svg"),
    image_read_svg("https://www.bundesliga.com/assets/clublogo/DFL-CLU-000003.svg"),
    image_read_svg("https://www.bundesliga.com/assets/clublogo/DFL-CLU-000004.svg"),
    image_read_svg("https://www.bundesliga.com/assets/clublogo/DFL-CLU-00000.svg")
  )
)

g=ggplot(data, aes(reorder(Team, Diff_home_perc),Diff_home_perc, fill = ind, image = image)) +
  ylab("Ratio of points from home games")+ylim(-0.3,0.3)+ylab("Difference")+xlab("Team")+
  geom_isotype_col(
    img_height = NULL, img_width = grid::unit(0.5, "null"),
    ncol = 1, nrow = 1, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none")+
  theme_minimal()+theme(
    plot.title = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    text = element_text(size=15),legend.title = element_blank(),legend.position="none")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy part is the axis text, e.g. you could add some labels for the groups via  `scale_x_discrete(labels = c("", "Bottom 3", "", "", "Top 3", ""))`. Another option would be to make use of faceting.

Concerning the positioning of the logos. I'm not sure whether this could be achieved via `ggtextures`. As far as I get it `ggtextures` is meant to add textures on column charts, which probably is the reason why one of the logos gets clipped off. Instead I would suggest to make use of the `ggtext` package which allows to add logos as text labels and gives you a lot of control on where to put the logos. One drawback is that `ggtext` does not work with `svg` so you first have to download the logos and convert them to `png`.

```r
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.12.3
#> Enabled features: cairo, fontconfig, freetype, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp
#> Disabled features: fftw, ghostscript, x11

# download svgs, convert to png and save
urls <- paste0(
  "https://www.bundesliga.com/assets/clublogo/DFL-CLU-",
  c("00000G", "000017", "000018", "000003", "000004", "000005"),
  ".svg"
)
lapply(urls, function(x) download.file(x, destfile = fs::path_file(x)))
fn <- fs::path_file(urls)
lapply(fn, function(x) image_write(image_convert(image_read_svg(x)), path = gsub("\\.svg", ".png", x), format = "png"))

library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)

data <- tibble(
  Diff_home_perc = c(-0.3, -0.2, -0.1, -0.05, 0.2, 0.3),
  Team = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
  ind = c("Green", "Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red"),
  label = gsub("\\.svg", ".png", fs::path_file(fn)),
  vjust = ifelse(Diff_home_perc < 0, 0, 1)
)
data$label <- paste0("<img src='", data$label, "' width = '40'/>")
data$vjust <- ifelse(abs(data$Diff_home_perc) < .1, 1 - data$vjust, data$vjust)
ggplot(data, aes(reorder(Team, Diff_home_perc), Diff_home_perc, fill = ind)) +
  ylab("Ratio of points from home games") +
  ylim(-0.3, 0.3) +
  ylab("Difference") +
  xlab("Team") +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2") +
  ggtext::geom_richtext(aes(label = label, vjust = vjust),
    label.colour = NA, fill = NA, label.padding = unit(c(0, 0.25, -.3, 0.25), "lines")
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    text = element_text(size = 15)
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("", "Bottom 3", "", "", "Top 3", ""))
```

[image]

Comment: This is incredible, thank you!